# Trouble extracting multiple HTML DOM elements for AJAX with Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, ajax

I'm trying to implement a feature on a web app where I have a menu of pizzas, and the price listed on each card (feature taken from Bootstrap) dynamically updates depending on the style (regular/sicilian), size (small/large) and name (cheese/special) of pizza selected. I'm using a loop to create all the cards by querying the database using ORM in the backend, which takes all existing pizzas the restaurant owner adds, and makes a menu item for each one. Then, I'm aiming to extract the name, style, and size selections for each, and give a dynamic render of the price of that specific type of pizza in the price area of the card, using AJAX, before implementing the checkout functionality whereby a user buys that pizza. The problem is mainly that I'm unsure how to extract the name, style, and size selections given that the cards are implemented using a templating loop, and also I think there are a few small errors littered through my AJAX/backend. But I suspect the solution would be something to do with Javascript's ForEach() after I extract an array of the styles from the cards? I really don't know how I'd go about proceeding. My code is:

**views.py:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Topping, Size, Pizza, Sub, Pasta, Platter, Salad, pizza_styles, sizes
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your views here.
def index(request): # this home page will be the menu page
    return render(request, "orders/index.html")

def pizza(request): # this home page will be the menu page
    styles = [x[0] for x in pizza_styles]
    # these lists have to be created because pizza_styles and sizes are naturally a list of tuples
    propSizes = [x[0] for x in sizes]
    context = {
    'pizzas': Pizza.objects.all(),
    'styles': styles,
    'sizes': propSizes,
    }
    print(propSizes, styles, Pizza.objects.first().name) # diagnostic purposes
    return render(request, "orders/pizza.html", context)

#below is the function I'm currently stuck on (the front end is the tough part I think)
def get_price(request):
    style = request.GET.get('style', None)
    size = request.GET.get('size', None)
    name = request.GET.get('name', None)
    data = {
    'price' = Pizza.objects.filter(name=name, style=style, size=size).price
    # get the pizza style, size, and type from the front end and query database on those filters to get price
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("pizza", views.pizza, name="pizza"),
    path("get_price", views.get_price, name='get_price'),
]
```

**pizza.html:**

```
{% extends "orders/index.html" %}
{% block item %}
  <main class="containerX">
<div class="row">
  {% for pizza in pizzas %}
        <div class="card border-primary mb-3" id="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title" id="name">{{ pizza.name }}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                <select id="style">
                  {% for style in styles %}
                      <option value="{{ style }}">{{ style }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                  </select>
                </p>
              <p class="card-text">
                <select id="size">
                  {% for size in sizes %}
                      <option value="{{ size }}">{{ size }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                  </select>
               </p>
              <p class="card-text" id="price"> price depending on selection </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
            </div>
        </div>
  {% empty %}
  <h2>No pizzas currently on offer. Sorry!</h2>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
  </main>


    <script>
        var size = document.querySelector('#size').value;
        var name = document.querySelector('#name').textContent;
        var style = document.querySelector('#style').value;
        var price = document.querySelector('#price').value;
        console.log(size, name, style, price)

        // load default price set up in python too

        (style.onchange || size.onchange)  = function(){
          // then send the ajax request
          $.ajax({
                  url: '/get_price', // implement this url that will send back data
                  data: { // communication with the backend is to get the price from the database
                    'size': size,
                        'name': name,
                        'style': style,
                  },
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function (data) {
                    // simply update price here
                      price = data['price']
                      console.log(price)
                  }
                });
        };
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

I have a rudimentary understanding of how AJAX and Django work, and think my code for views, urls, and pizza.html are all, in principle, correct, but there are small implementation details I can't quite get a handle on, despite days of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to listen to the change event on the actual value but you need to listen to the Dom node. Also ensure that you are including jquery before your JavaScript as $.ajax is a jquery function. Try changing your JavaScript to the following:

```
<script>
    var size = document.querySelector('#size');
    var name = document.querySelector('#name').textContent;
    var style = document.querySelector('#style');
    var price = document.querySelector('#price').value;
    console.log(size, name, style, price)

    // load default price set up in python too

    (style.onchange || size.onchange)  = function(e){
      var styleValue = e.target.value;
      var sizeValue = e.target.value;
      // then send the ajax request
      $.ajax({
              url: '/get_price', // implement this url that will send back data
              data: { // communication with the backend is to get the price from the database
                'size': sizeValue,
                    'name': name,
                    'style': styleValue,
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (data) {
                // simply update price here
                  price = data['price']
                  console.log(price)
              }
            });
    };
</script>
```

Let me know if you have further problems and I’ll try help.

Comment: 1) There are going to be several cards with the id "size" and "style" all of which need to be listening for a change in the dropdowns, so this doesn't work, and 2) the DOM node (the actual HTML) remains unchanged of course no matter the selection, but depending on the selection, the value outputted by "document.querySelector('#size').value" is what is changing, so I don't understand what you mean by I should grab the DOM node not the value. In any case--this code isn't working either--any ideas? I've included jQ; the error is: "Uncaught TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function" @ the ||

Comment: @TanishqKumar the JavaScript event is on the Dom node not the value itself and your are looking up an Id so there can only be one element with that id, I think you need to look up JavaScript events